# Unpacking into a list

Tags: python

Is there any difference in Python between unpacking into a tuple:

```
x, y, z = v
```

and unpacking into a list?

```
[x, y, z] = v
```

Comment: Have you tried it? What happened?

Comment: I have tried **this case**, and of course, the same "happened". I have asked, since theoretically it could have different meanings in various contexts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python assignment destructuring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24999875/python-assignment-destructuring)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Absolutely nothing, even down to the bytecode (using [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html)):

```
>>> def list_assign(args):
    [x, y, z] = args
    return x, y, z

>>> def tuple_assign(args):
    x, y, z = args
    return x, y, z

>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(list_assign)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (args) 
              3 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          3 
              6 STORE_FAST               1 (x) 
              9 STORE_FAST               2 (y) 
             12 STORE_FAST               3 (z) 

  3          15 LOAD_FAST                1 (x) 
             18 LOAD_FAST                2 (y) 
             21 LOAD_FAST                3 (z) 
             24 BUILD_TUPLE              3 
             27 RETURN_VALUE         
>>> dis.dis(tuple_assign)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (args) 
              3 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          3 
              6 STORE_FAST               1 (x) 
              9 STORE_FAST               2 (y) 
             12 STORE_FAST               3 (z) 

  3          15 LOAD_FAST                1 (x) 
             18 LOAD_FAST                2 (y) 
             21 LOAD_FAST                3 (z) 
             24 BUILD_TUPLE              3 
             27 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: I tried to get a source; the best I could find is [this](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements).

Answer (score 2):

No. In fact the `x, y, z = v` is a shorthand for:

```
(x, y, z) = v
```

... which is unpacking in a tuple. The same behavior happens:

```
>>> v = (1, 3, 4)
>>> [x, y, z] = v
>>> x, y, z
(1, 3, 4)
>>> x, y, z = v
>>> x, y, z
(1, 3, 4)
```