# Python assignment destructuring

Tags: python, destructuring

These three expressions seem to be equivalent:

```
a,b,c = line.split()
(a,b,c) = line.split()
[a,b,c] = line.split()
```

Do they compile to the same code?

Which one is more pythonic?

Comment: You need some kind of grouping for `[[a]] = b`, e.g., and `((a,),) = b` doesn’t look particularly nice either. As for which one’s more readable when that’s not necessary, it’s up to you.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

According to `dis`, they all get compiled to the same bytecode:

```
>>> def f1(line):
...  a,b,c = line.split()
... 
>>> def f2(line):
...  (a,b,c) = line.split()
... 
>>> def f3(line):
...  [a,b,c] = line.split()
... 
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(f1)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (line)
              3 LOAD_ATTR                0 (split)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              9 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          3
             12 STORE_FAST               1 (a)
             15 STORE_FAST               2 (b)
             18 STORE_FAST               3 (c)
             21 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             24 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis.dis(f2)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (line)
              3 LOAD_ATTR                0 (split)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              9 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          3
             12 STORE_FAST               1 (a)
             15 STORE_FAST               2 (b)
             18 STORE_FAST               3 (c)
             21 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             24 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis.dis(f3)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (line)
              3 LOAD_ATTR                0 (split)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              9 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          3
             12 STORE_FAST               1 (a)
             15 STORE_FAST               2 (b)
             18 STORE_FAST               3 (c)
             21 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             24 RETURN_VALUE
```

So they should all have the same efficiency. As far as which is most Pythonic, it's somewhat down to opinion, but I would favor either the first or (to a lesser degree) the second option. Using the square brackets is confusing because it looks like you're creating a list (though it turns out you're not).

Comment: "Which one is more pythonic?" -- I'd say the first option since it has less syntax and is more "readable."

Comment: @Kevin It's the same on Python 3.2, at least (that's all I have access to right now).