# Error related to input file, ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Tags: python

I am trying to run the following code from a coding book I have but I get this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex20.py", line 3, in 
    script, input_file = argv
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

I have created a txt file called input_file and tried other troubleshooting methods but I continue to get errors.

```
from sys import argv

script, input_file = argv

def print_all(f):
        print f.read()

def rewind(f):
    f.seek(0)

def print_a_line(line_count, f):
    print line_count, f.readline()

current_line = open(input_file)

print "First let's print the whole file:\n"

print_all(current_file)

print("Now lets rewind, kind of like a tape")

current_line = 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_line)

current_line = current_line + 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)
```

I expect it to print and work as coded.

Comment: Was the `input_file` provided as command line param? Please check.

Comment: How did you run the script? What arguments did you pass to it?

Comment: Why are you setting the script, and the input_file to the package you just imported? - I mean argv comes back with a list you need to define what you set to what... script, input_file = argv[0], argv[1]

Comment: I am assuming the script is the code its self and the input_file is a text file int he same file that has the code/.py script. I Am running it via terminal aka "python ex20.py", I am setting it because that is what the book told me to do.

Comment: bash-4.3$ python ex20.py input_file.txt
First let's print the whole file:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex20.py", line 18, in <module>
    print_all(current_file)
NameError: name 'current_file' is not defined

I am using python 2 and this is the error I get when attempting to provide the two parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
script, input_file = argv
```

According to [[Python 3.Docs]: sys.argv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv):

> The list of command line arguments passed to a Python script.

So, regardless an argument was passed or not to the script (or if a script was passed to the interpreter), it's always a list (sequence).

Since on the left side you have 2 variables (*script* and *input_file*), **the list should also contain 2 elements** (according to error text yours only contains one - meaning that no argument was given to the script).

Behind the scenes, [[Python 3.Docs]: More Control Flow Tools - Unpacking Argument Lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) happens.

A common way of dealing with this kind of situation, is checking how many elements are in the list:

```py
if len(argv) != 2:
    raise SystemExit("Script should receive exactly one argument!")
```

Make sure to also pass a value for your input file, when you invoke the interpreter (your script) from *cmdline*.

***@EDIT0***:

**Technically, this is beyond the (original) question scope**.

The code contains a bunch of nonsense parts (mainly because confusing *current_file* and *current_line* - which denotes bad naming). I'm not going to insist on them, but paste the code as it should look like:

```py
import sys


def print_all(f):
    print(f.read())


def rewind(f):
    f.seek(0)


def print_a_line(line_number, f):
    print(line_number, f.readline())


_, input_file_name = sys.argv

input_file = open(input_file_name)

print("First, let's print the whole file:\n")
print_all(input_file)
print("Now lets rewind, kind of like a tape:\n")
rewind(input_file)
current_line = 1
print_a_line(current_line, input_file)
current_line += 1
print_a_line(current_line, input_file)
```

Note that although you mentioned using *Python 2*, *print*s will also work in *Python 3*.

Comment: I am using python2, I get this error when I provide the 2 parameters requested: 
bash-4.3$ python ex20.py input_file.txt
First let's print the whole file:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex20.py", line 18, in <module>
    print_all(current_file)
NameError: name 'current_file' is not defined

Comment: Not really but I was reading a python2.7 book and decided to ditch it because 3.xx is the modern version. No use in learning 2.7 when I could learn 3.xx and just "reverse learn" any code I may have to patch up or what ever the case may be in the future.

Comment: Note that you don't have to accept an answer unless it solves your problem. Hmm, what didn't work? Let me know so I can modify (improve) the answer. Anyway (the code I posted) it should work on both *Python 3* and 2 (as it solved the problem in the question and several others).

Answer (score 0):

This error means that `argv` did not have "enough values to unpack", i.e. you tried to assign `script` and `input_file` from the `argv` variable by doing what is called [destructuring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24999875/python-assignment-destructuring), but `argv` had only one value (the name of the script)

It seems you ran your script without supplying an argument (the input_file).
You should run your script in the following way:

```py
python ex20.py 'path/to/input_file'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem occur when you have, not surprisingly "more than 1 value to unpack", meaning that `argv` is smaller then the number of variables you want to assign to.

you should make sure your `argv` length is exactly 2 if you want your line of code to work, or just access the `argv` values through `argv` without the assignment, but, if you do want to keep it as is i suggest a quick test before :

```
if len(argv) != 2:
    exit()
```

and the rest of your code afterward. but you need to remember to run your code with the appropriate amount of args' like so:

`python <your_script_file>.py arg1`

in that way replace `arg1` with the value you want to be assign to `input_file`, since `argv[0]` is always the name of the script/file you are running.

IMHO you should use a lib like `argumentParser` or something like that.